# Limit the time to choose from up to a specific hour

Tags: c#, winforms, time, datepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` in my form application in the format of 00:00. I need the user to be able to choose time up until 05:00 only. How can I do this?

Comment: I was thinking to do an event on the up button of the date time picker, check if the value is less than 5 it's ok, if its not disable up button

Comment: at least 75% of your time as a (novice) programmer will be spent researching how to get things done. It's important that you get to know your sources. Search engines, MSDN (when applicable),  StackOverflow, searching through pdfs, books, asking colleagues when you get really stuck. Preferably in that order. I'm not saying that to diss you, it's just an observation.

Comment: It seems he _did_ try (see his comment to Rotem's answer), but Visual Studio's Designer doesn't show that as an option (-changing the _Time_).

Answer (score 3):

Set the [`MaxDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) property of your control to whatever you like.
This will limit the selection up until this `Datetime`.

Comment: but doesn't 'MaxDate' allow you to choose a date only? I only need time

Comment: @studentProgrammer `MaxDate` is a `DateTime` - it has both Date and Time

Comment: The value is a `DateTime` value. In includes both a date and a time.

Comment: Yes I know.. When I go to properties, MaxDate, it's only allowed to change the date and not the time however :/

Comment: Type in the time, it wont kick out.

Comment: and how can I make the date always start from DateTime.Now + 5 minutes?

Comment: Add `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);` to the form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Check these properties: [DisplayDateStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [DisplayDateEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like the following
lets say I want to set my time to be 6:30 you could do this

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 6, 30, 0 )
```

Look at MSDN Site for further Reference

[DateTimePicker.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx)